# jQuery keeps putting a cache buster in my CDN scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

I have a script that uses `$.get( ... )` to pull a piece of HTML from my server, and render it inside a `<div>` with `$.html`. Sometimes I have `<script>` tags in the pulled HTML, and I noticed that jQuery is putting a cache buster parameter in the request for these scripts and it's causing the browser to request again for scripts that have already been loaded.

For example:

[image]

Any idea how I can disable this behavior?

The script tags don't have the `_` param attached to them so it isn't my HTML that's the problem.

Also, `<script>` tags that aren't rendered with `$.html` aren't exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: jQuery's cachebuster parameter looks like `_=123456890`. Whatever you're seeing, it's not coming from jQuery.

Comment: it's the exact same HTML code being rendered. If rendered with a browser request, it doesn't have that parameter. If rendered with $.html it does. It has to be jQuery.

Comment: I think you're seeing the browser's internal representation of the `eval()` that's used to execute the `<script>`.

Comment: Nope. it's jQuery. innerHTML doesn't exhibit the same behavior:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7j5vvk2v/ try uncommenting/commenting those lines

Comment: innerHTML doesn't interpret scripts at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When jQuery sees a `<script src="URL">` tag in the HTML, it uses `$.getScript()` internally to load the script. By default, this sends a cachebuster, but you can override the default AJAX options by calling `$.ajaxSetup()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: true
    });
    var x = '<script src="https://d9zdvmiwibsh5.cloudfront.net/js/json.js">';
    $('#test').html(x);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7j5vvk2v/2/)

Comment: This is perfect, but any way I can make it just do that for type=text/javascript? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want that level of control, you'll have to do the loading yourself, instead of using `.html()`.

Comment: Decided to go with RequireJS instead, but I'll mark this as accepted since you put me on the right track :)

Comment: If you are using $.getJSON(), you can simply append the current time of the request, e.g. 
$.getJSON('/path/to/my/json/file.js?' + new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
    // do magic
});

Comment: @TimothyDalton That's a cachebuster, which is what he *doesn't* want.

Comment: Oops, thanks @Barmar - I guess I lost my concentration there :)